# iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 VBO vertex count limit: Once exceeded, CPU bound

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am testing the rendering of extremely large 3d meshes, and I am currently testing on an iPhone 5 (I also have an iPad 3).

I have here two screenshots of Instruments with a profiling run. The first one is rendering a 1.3M vertex mesh, and the second is rendering a 2.1M vertex mesh.

[image]
[image]

The blue histogram-bar at the top shows CPU load, and it can be seen that for the first mesh is hovering at around ~10% CPU load so the GPU is doing most of the heavy lifting. The mesh is very detailed and my point-light-with-specular shader makes it look quite impressive if I say so myself, as it is able to render consistently above 20 frames per second. Oh, and 4x MSAA is enabled as well!

However, once I step up to a 2 million+ vertex mesh, everything goes to crap as we see here a massive CPU bound situation, and all instruments report 1 frame per second performance.

So, it's pretty clear that somewhere between these two assets (and I will admit that they are both tremendously large meshes to be loading in under one single VBO), whether it is the vertex buffer size or the index buffer size that is over the limit, some limit is being surpassed by the 2megavertex (462K tris) mesh.

So, the question is, what is this limit, and how can I query it? It would really be very preferable if I can have some reasonable assurance that my app will function well without exhaustively testing every device.

I also see an alternative approach to this problem, which is to stick to a known good VBO size limit (I have read about 4MB being a good limit), and basically just have the CPU work a little bit harder if the mesh being rendered is monstrous. With a 100MB VBO, having it in 4MB chunks (segmenting the mesh into 25 draw calls) does not really sound that bad.

But, I'm still curious. How can I check the max size, in order to work around the CPU fallback? Could I be running into an out of memory condition, and Apple is simply applying a CPU based workaround (oh LORD have mercy, 2 million vertices in immediate mode...)?

Answer (score 2):

In pure OpenGL, there are two implementation-defined attributes: `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES` and `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES`. When exceeded performance can drop off a cliff in some implementations.

I spent a while looking through the OpenGL ES specification for the equivalent and could not find it. Chances are it's burried in one of the OES or vendor-specific extensions on OpenGL ES. Nevertheless, there is a very real hardware limit to the number of elements you can draw and the number of vertices. After a point with too many indices, you can exceed the capacity of the post-T&L cache. 2 million is a lot for a single draw call, in lieu of being able to query the OpenGL ES implementation for this information, I'd try successively lower powers-of-two until you dial it back to the sweet spot.

65,536 used to be a sweet spot on DX9 hardware. That was the limit for 16-bit indices and was always guaranteed to be below the maximum hardware vertex count. Chances are it'll work for OpenGL ES class hardware too...

Comment: Indeed, and with limiting VBOs to a 16-bit size my IBOs can be always allocated with short uints, further reducing precious shared memory consumption. I think that reason alone is more than enough to convince me to put a limit at that "sweet spot". Given the bare minimum for vertices, for which we have 3 position and 3 normal 4-byte float components for 24*64K = ~1.5MB this is already plenty of space to put a good chunk of geometry into.

Comment: "*GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES and GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES.*" Note that these only apply to `glDrawRangeElements`, and are primarily for when you are using client memory (which was why it was first introduced in 1.2: so implementations could tell what the range of vertex data to be used was without having to read through the entire index list). The 65536 "sweet spot" (for NVIDIA GPUs) was primarily due to their inability to use 32-bit integer indices in hardware. No GL 3.x-capable hardware has any significant issues in either regard.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Would you say that most OpenGL ES 2.0 hardware is OpenGL 3.0 capable? I know there are a number of embedded GPUs with geometry shader support, but it's not exposed in GL ES 2. So it's a bit of a grey area in my mind as to what generation of desktop GPU to compare the typical OpenGL ES 2 GPU to feature-wise :)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: "*Would you say that most OpenGL ES 2.0 hardware is OpenGL 3.0 capable?*" Even ignoring GS's, no. I don't see any UBO support from pre-ES 3.0 mobile hardware. There's RG support, but no RGTC extension. I don't see an integer texture extension or any extension to allow the use of (real) integers in shaders. NVIDIA's ES 2.0 hardware comes closest to desktop 3.x support, and even they didn't make extensions to expose those features (though they made plenty of others). Because their ES 2.0 hardware can't do them.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: "*So it's a bit of a grey area in my mind as to what generation of desktop GPU to compare the typical OpenGL ES 2 GPU to feature-wise*" Agreed. Which is why it was inappropriate to compare those `glDrawRangeElements` limitations to the issue that he may be having. That was my main point.

Comment: Boy is it a slight logistical pain to split meshes into chunks of 64K verts, and dealing with segmenting the indices as well. Will it be safe for me to stuff around 6 times that number of short ints into an IBO? Do you guys remember if `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES` is usually larger than `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES` or not?

Comment: @StevenLu: Yes, that was just an example of the sort of considerations that had to be made on older generation hardware. Honestly, since you're targeting iOS, Apple usually has a set of best practices for their hardware. I would expect them to list a target number of vertices per-batch or something for the PowerVR hardware all iOS devices use. Try starting here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/OpenGLES/Conceptual/OpenGLESHardwarePlatformGuide_iOS/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

Comment: I don't think I saw anything in there that mentions size limits. I figure Apple is not likely to have anything constructive to say about dealing with more than 64K vertices. And in all fairness most games wouldn't be getting even close to that on a single draw call.